# IIS7 javascript error on remote machine only

Tags: javascript, iis, iis-7

I have a working asp.net app with a lot of telerik controls, jQuery, dynamic data and lots of aax calls.

On my dev machine everything runs fine. No errors. Deployed to the web server (iis7 on w2k8) the app runs fine when seen in IE on the server. But IE on any remote machine (tested on XP and Vista)) gives me a expected ';' javascript error? Most javascript seems to be working ok though. Anyone has seen this before or has a clue what might be wrong? I think it must be a iis7 setting but what?

Edit: Firefox does not give a javascript error, only IE (on 3 different machines)

Edit2: I found that one of my .js files was delivered to IE with the following code(it's part of  class, but how does that headerinfo come there??????):

```
    get_numVideos: function()
    {
        return this._numVideHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: ue;
    },
```

Henk.

Comment: Re: Edit2; how does this explain "Firefox does not give a javascript error"? Is the problem still occurring with IE?

Comment: Nope, problem is completely gone. Also the remote desktop connection that was disconnecting each time with encryption problems now works perfectly. Don't have a clue why firefox did work and mstsc and IE not, but setting that property did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 7 should not be the source of your issue.

For troubleshooting issus like this. I suggest - 
From a remote machine  - view source and put the URLs of all supporting JS scripts in IE to download them directly. One or more will probally give you an error message or, more likely, a permissions issue.

Also - place the public- facing URL in the remote computer's Trusted Sites list. DOes the error still happen? From the webserver this would be trusted as an intranet site. IE could be blocking something that it does not trust. This will not solve your problem, but it will put you on the right path to solving the issue.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) to inspect the HTML and JavaScript returned by the server. If IIS7 has somehow modified your pages, you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

After also experiencing encryption problems on the remote desktop connection to the webserver, I found the solution!

I appears that I had to disable IPv4 large send offload on my NIC.

So at the end it was not IIS7, or ASP.NET but a nic propery :(

Henk

Answer (score -1):

Are they running the same version if IE7?

Are any of the scripts generating a 404 error?

Comment: No 404's, but sometimes I also see in my Dynamic Data backend that it can't find the stylesheet!!!!!!!!!

All the machines have all latest updates so I guess the IE7 versions are the same?